# MPAndroidChart - how to draw a circle in the last entry only?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), Is there a way to draw only one circle in line chart?, this means that only the end of the line will be represented be a circle as shown in this image: 
[image]

@PhilJay

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well a workaround could be that you always put the last entry in a separate `DataSet` as well which has `setDrawCircles(...)` enabled. So you add the last entry to a separate `DataSet` and to you actual `DataSet` as well.

As soon as there is a "new" last entry, clear the circle-dataset and add that new entry to it.

**Pseudo example**

```
public void add(Entry e) {

   actualDataSet.addEntry(e);

   circleDataSet.clear();
   circleDataSet.addEntry(e);

   chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
   chart.invalidate(); // redraw
}
```

Comment: Amazing solution!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Um finding it difficulty to understand this concept, may someone demonstrate this in full code?

Answer (score 10):

I have searched and struggled a bit because of this and in my opinion the best solution is to use `setIcon` which is quite a recent method and won't get messed in case you have an animation. Here is an example:

```
dataSet.getEntryForIndex(position).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.myDrawable));
```

This will work for any position, in case you wish to have different points with different drawables

Comment: If you are using more than one dataset make sure you are not having problems with their size, else it might not work.

Comment: um having problems with index